# What is the difference between using Module and using mapped layouts folder when deploying files (images/css/js) to SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, mapped-folder, hive

What is the difference between using Module item and using mapped layouts folder when deploying files (images/css/js) to SharePoint?

I guess 1 difference is that module allows you to deploy the file into the libraries (content db) as well as the hive ([reference - check the defn of Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms434127%28v=office.15%29.aspx), whereas, the mapped layout folder allows us to deploy files only to the hive. Any more in terms of security/access/delays, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Module` could be treated as a more advanced and flexible way to provisioning site assets.

With Module:

- files could to be targeted to a specific site
- files could be managed by users using designer tools (SPD)
- some assets could not be hosted in layout folder and therefore
  provisioned via `Mapped folder`. For example, xsl files for Content
  Query web part could be referenced from Style Library in site
  collection only